# Can't remove GPT data from MBR

Tags: installation, partitioning, disk, mbr, gpt

I am having difficulty getting the Ubuntu installer (and gparted) to recognize the partitions on my MBR type disk. Other operating systems and disk tools read the disk structure and the files on it fine. I have used fixparts to write a new MBR but the issue persists. I assume the issue stems from the Protective MBR data still present on the disk but I am at a loss as to how to remove it while preserving my NTFS data partition.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> c:\Users\mike\Desktop\fixparts>fixparts 3: FixParts 0.8.8
>
> Loading MBR data from 3:
>
> Warning: 0xEE partition doesn't start on sector 1. This can cause
>   problems in some OSes.
>
> MBR command (? for help):

Running gdisk shows

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



c:\Users\mike\Desktop\fixparts>gdisk 3: GPT fdisk (gdisk) version
0.8.7

Partition table scan:
   MBR: MBR only
   BSD: not present
   APM: not present
   GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions to GPT format!
***************************************************************

************************************************************************ 
Most versions of Windows cannot boot from a GPT disk, and most varieties prior to Vista cannot read GPT disks. Therefore, you should exit now unless you understand the implications of converting MBR to GPT or creating a new GPT disk layout!
************************************************************************

Are you SURE you want to continue? (Y/N): y

Command (? for help): p Disk 3:: 2930277168 sectors, 1.4 TiB Logical sector size: 512 bytes Disk identifier (GUID): BFE92CE8-F93D-4141-82B8-816AD06FB36E Partition table holds up to 128 entries First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 2930277134 Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries Total free space is 163846893 sectors (78.1 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
     1     163842048      2930272255   1.3 TiB     0700  Microsoft basic data

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): o

Disk size is 2930277168 sectors (1.4 TiB) MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000 MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1   2930277167   primary     0xEE

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): q
```

Comment: Please boot an Ubuntu live CD and type `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print`. Edit your post with the output of both of those commands.

Comment: Looks like the issue resolved itself after booting to the Live CD. I have formatted the empty space to BTRFS and am installing Ubuntu on it now through VMWare. Thanks for developing the tools.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gdisk zap command or a MBR rebuild took care of the offending GPT data but didn't take effect until after a reboot.